# How to create a table view programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, orientation

I need to use UITable View in my application and it has to support for both Landscape and portrait orientations.

If i Drag UItableview from the Interface builder directly then how can i control it exactly

If not then suggest me to do the same programmatically.

Thanks 
Rizwan

Comment: try to accept your previous anwers

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;//Returns the no of sections in the tableview
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 5;//Returns the no of rows in the tableview
    }

//This method is called everytime when a row is created.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text =@"tableview";

        return cell;

    }
```